# Why is this clearly wrong code produce no error in irb?

Tags: ruby, typeerror, irb

I have just started on my adventure towards becoming a Full Stack Developer, and I am learning how to use the command line quickly, basic Ruby syntax, etc (beginner stuff!).

The current exercise I am working on asks me to define a class with a single method and then call the method.  The trick is that the given code should produce an error, which I am supposed to analyze.

However, even though I am given the code to type into my irb console, I'm not getting an error message (I should receive the error "TypeError: no implicit conversion of Fixnum into String"). I just get... nothing.

I'm sure this is simple, but googling "how do i make this error" (and similar) is unfortunately not helping.  I feel silly even asking this (ie. "how do I make this code break?"), but it's important I understand the whole process and here I am struggling.

So this is what **should** produce the error "TypeError: no implicit conversion of Fixnum into String":

```
class ArgumentEchoer
  def echo_argument(argument)
    p "You just inputted a value: " + argument
  end 
end

instance = ArgumentEchoer.new
instance.echo_argument(5)
```

And this is what I am doing in my terminal:

```
natalieimac-3:~ tabalie$ irb
irb(main):011:1> class ArgumentEchoer
irb(main):012:2>   def echo_argument(argument)
irb(main):013:3>     p "You just inputted a value: " + argument
irb(main):014:3>   end 
irb(main):015:2> end
irb(main):016:1> instance = ArgumentEchoer.new
irb(main):017:1> instance.echo_argument(5)
irb(main):018:1>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What are you exactly trying to do?? I am getting the error if I follow your code: `"string"+1 #=> TypeError: no implicit conversion of Fixnum into String`

Comment: It turns out my irb console was hung up - I actually wanted the error (it's an exercise in trying to figure out error messages ;) ).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rereading your question, it looks like you actually are just stuck inside a syntax error in your irb console. Hit `^C` a few times and start over.

You can tell because **a)** the prompt includes the level of embeddedness (e.g. `...1>`, `...2>`) and **b)** the lines that should be executing and returning values are not executing, indicating that irb is waiting for the syntactic end of whatever expression it thinks you are in the middle of.

A good way to tell whether your irb is hung up on a syntax error is just to try typing any simple expression, and see if it returns a value (indicated by the `=>` output). Here's the simplest example:

```
$ irb
>> 1
=> 1
>>
```

If you and irb are stuck in a syntax disagreement, you won't get a return value:

```
$ irb
>> if
?> 1
>>
```

Comment: `control-d` also ends the input stream, so it can be 'safer' than `control-c`  If all else fails, you can `control-z` to place it in the background and then kill the process.  Editing code in IRB is not comfortable, though.  You can usually create your code in a file, the `load 'filename.rb'` into your session.  Use load, it will load it as many times as you want to make changes.  (as opposed to require, which will refuse to load the file again, returning false instead.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case anyone else runs into this...

I followed the advice above - I exited the irb console and started over.  Now it is working properly!

Now on to my "real" assignment - analyzing the resulting error :)

```
irb(main):019:0> irb_exit
natalieimac-3:~ tabalie$ irb
irb(main):001:0> class ArgumentEchoer
irb(main):002:1>   def echo_argument(argument)
irb(main):003:2>     p "You just inputted a value: " + argument
irb(main):004:2>   end 
irb(main):005:1> end
=> nil
irb(main):006:0> instance = ArgumentEchoer.new
=> #<ArgumentEchoer:0x007fc2ac0572a8>
irb(main):007:0> instance.echo_argument(5)
TypeError: no implicit conversion of Fixnum into String
    from (irb):3:in `+'
    from (irb):3:in `echo_argument'
    from (irb):7
    from /usr/bin/irb:12:in `<main>'
irb(main):008:0>
```